# FluentMigrator: How to set default schema for MigrationRunner

Tags: .net-core, fluent-migrator

I have a multi-tenanted database.  The tenant-specific data is stored inside it's own (PostgreSQL) schema.

I'd like to be able to use FluentMigrator to deploy new tenants as required.  I've set up an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/andyRokit/FluentMigratorDemo) where a HTTP post to an endpoint will deploy a schema.  However deploys it to the public schema by default.  I'd like to be able to specify the schema to deploy to.

I.e.

```
public class TenantService: ITenantService {
  private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

  public TenantService(IServiceProvider provider) {
    _provider = provider;
  }

  public void Create(string tenantName) {
    using(var scope = _provider.CreateScope()) {
      var migrationRunner = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMigrationRunner>();
      // TODO:  Set the default schema = tenantName
      migrationRunner.MigrateUp();
    }
  }
}
```

How do I set the default schema for the MigrationRunner?

**Edit:**  I've updated the GitHub repo to reflect the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with this exact same issue and also the same enviroments. .Net-core, FluentMigrator and Postgre with different schema's. I have been using the Obsolete functions and allready noticed that I had to create my own: ConventionSet. I was able to fix this in the following, where I first must say: Thank you for your git, this helped me to also figure out my problem, here goes:

First thing I did was manually create a database and a schema with a different name then: public. Then I adjusted the startup.cs

```
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConventionSet>(new DefaultConventionSet("tenanta", null));
        services.AddFluentMigratorCore();
        services.ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
                .AddPostgres()                    
                .WithGlobalConnectionString("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=12345678;CommandTimeout=20;database=nameofdatabase")
                .ScanIn(typeof(AddSecuritySchema).Assembly).For.Migrations());
        services.AddSingleton<ITenantService, TenantService>();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

With the above change, where we add a: new DefaultConventionSet with the schemaname I could finally run migrations on a different schema then public. But I also want this to be on-the-fly. So in order to achieve that (not sure if correct) I did the following:

```
public class TenantService: ITenantService {
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    public TenantService(IServiceProvider provider) {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void Create(string tenantName) {

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                        .AddSingleton<IConventionSet>(new DefaultConventionSet(tenantName, null))
                        .AddFluentMigratorCore()
                        .ConfigureRunner(r => r.AddPostgres()
                                                .WithGlobalConnectionString("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=12345678;CommandTimeout=20;database=databasename")
                                                .WithRunnerConventions(new MigrationRunnerConventions()
                                                {

                                                })
                                                .ScanIn(typeof(AddSecuritySchema).Assembly).For.Migrations()
                        )
                        .Configure<RunnerOptions>(opt =>
                        {
                            opt.TransactionPerSession = true;
                        })
                        .BuildServiceProvider(false);

        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var migrationRunner = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMigrationRunner>();
            migrationRunner.MigrateUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Offcourse it's important to first register the ConventionSet ;)